# Efficient database synchronization between clients - server in 2019

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to keep in sync Client with postgreSQL database (only data that are loaded from database, not entire database, 50+ db tables and a lot of collections inside entities). As recently I have added server based on Spring-REST API to my application I could manage those changes maybe differently/more efficient that would require less work. So untill now my approach was to add psql notification that triggers json

```
CREATE TRIGGER extChangesOccured 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON xxx_table 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notifyUsers();
```

the client then receive the json built as:

```
json_build_object(
                          'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
                          'action', TG_OP,
                          'id', data,
                          'session', session_app_name);
```

compare if this change is made by this client or any other and fetch the new data from database.

Then on client side new object is manually "rewritten", something like method copyFromObject(new_entity) and variables are being overriden (including collections, avoid transient etc...).

This approach requires to keep copyFromObject method for each entity (hmm still can be optimized with reflections)

Problems with my approach is:

1. requires some work when modifying variables (can be optimized using reflections)
2. entire new entity is loaded when changed by some client

I am curious of Your solutions to keep clients in sync with db, generally I have desktop client here and the client loads a lot of data from database which must be sync, loading database takes even 1min on the app start depends on chosen data-period which should be fetched

The perfect solution would be to have some engine that would fetch/override only those variables in entities that was really changed and make it automatically.

Comment: Why would the data need to be up to date all the time? Why not just update data in a given interval (batching maybe?)?

Comment: under the hood notificatins are fetched in some interval like every 10s or so. I have for example Invoices which have to be updated on the others clients when change occures (imagine that someone add some note to invoice or change the content of invoice

Comment: Depending on how your application is implemented, you can trigger the notifications on application level instead of database level. Or you have different "views" in your application. I.e. the invoice view which only lists the invoices. Then the user can reload just that view manually, or you reload a single entry before the user tries to edit it (think double click to open invoice). The upcoming dialog then has the refreshed data

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to implement Optimistic Lock? It will prevent user from persisting data if the entity was changed after the user fetched it.

Or

You can use 3rd party apps for DB synchronization. I've played some time ago with [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) and you can find an excessive tutorial about Client synchronization here: [React client synchronization](https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime-mysql-java)
Of course pusher is not the only one solution, and I'm not related to the dev team of that app by at all.

Comment: 1. Optimistic Lock does not solve my problem which is simlify/optimize the solution, it is just another implementation to find out if entity on the client should be updated
2. I started this topic to find "this" db synchronization engine :) I have seen spring sync but last update was in 2015 y

Comment: only one remark - if you prefer to try the app I suggested (or similar) you should know that the overall performance will fall a lot. At least in the test systems I've used such real time sync the performance fall like twice.

Answer (score 0):

For my purpose I have implemented AVL Tree based loaded entities and database synchronization engine that creates repositiories based on the loaded entities from hibernate and asynchronously search throught all the fields in entities and rewrites/merge all the same fields (so that if some field (pk) is the same entity like the one in repository, it replaces it)

In this way synchronization with database is easy as it comes to find the externally changed entity in the repository (so basically in the AVL Tree which is O(log n)) and rewrite its fields.